# The name 'Npm' does not exist in the current context during Cake build

Tags: jenkins, cakebuild

I am running a Cake build on a Jenkins build server and am getting

```
error CS0101: The name 'Npm' does not exist in the current context
```

The task looks like this

```
Task("NpmInstall")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        Npm.FromPath("./src/MyProject/").Install();
    });
```

The Cake build works perfectly on my development machine with Visual Studio 2017  installed so I know the script is good, but for some reason it throws this error on the Jenkins build server. I am guessing I have some piece of tooling installed on my development machine that doesn't exist on the Jenkins machine, but I can't seem to find what that is.

Below is the diagnostic output from the last build

```
Preparing to run build script...
Chocolatey v0.10.5
Nothing to change. Config already set.
Chocolatey v0.10.5
Installing the following packages:
gitversion.portable
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
GitVersion.Portable v4.0.0-beta0011 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 0 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Warnings:
 - gitversion.portable - GitVersion.Portable v4.0.0-beta0011 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
Running build script...
Module directory does not exist.
Analyzing build script...
Analyzing C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/release-1.0.0/build.cake...
Processing build script...
Installing addins...
Package Cake.Npm has already been installed.
The addin Cake.Npm will reference Cake.Npm.dll.
Creating script session...
Adding reference to mscorlib.dll...
Adding reference to System.Core.dll...
Adding reference to Cake.Core.dll...
Adding reference to Cake.Common.dll...
Adding reference to Cake.exe...
Adding reference to System.dll...
Adding reference to System.Xml.dll...
Adding reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll...
Adding reference to System.Data.dll...
Adding reference to Cake.Npm.dll...
Importing namespace Cake.Common...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.AppVeyor...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.AppVeyor.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.Bamboo...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.Bamboo.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.BitbucketPipelines...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.BitbucketPipelines.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.Bitrise...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.Bitrise.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.ContinuaCI...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.ContinuaCI.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.GitLabCI...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.GitLabCI.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.GoCD...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.GoCD.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.Jenkins...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.Jenkins.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.MyGet...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.TeamCity...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.TFBuild...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.TFBuild.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.TravisCI...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Build.TravisCI.Data...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Diagnostics...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.IO...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.IO.Paths...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Net...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Security...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Solution...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Solution.Project...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Solution.Project.Properties...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Solution.Project.XmlDoc...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Text...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Cake...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.ApiKey...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Config...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Features...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Install...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.New...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Pack...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Pin...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Push...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Sources...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Uninstall...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Chocolatey.Upgrade...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotCover...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotCover.Analyse...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotCover.Cover...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotCover.Merge...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotCover.Report...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.Build...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.Execute...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.Pack...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.Publish...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.Restore...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.Run...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.Test...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.DupFinder...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Fixie...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitLink...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitReleaseManager...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitReleaseManager.AddAssets...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitReleaseManager.Close...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitReleaseManager.Create...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitReleaseManager.Export...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitReleaseManager.Publish...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitReleaseNotes...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.GitVersion...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.ILMerge...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.ILRepack...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.InnoSetup...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.InspectCode...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.MSTest...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NSIS...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Add...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Init...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Install...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Pack...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Push...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.SetApiKey...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.SetProxy...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Sources...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Update...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.NUnit...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.OctopusDeploy...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.OpenCover...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.ReportGenerator...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.ReportUnit...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.Roundhouse...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.SignTool...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.SpecFlow...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.SpecFlow.StepDefinitionReport...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.SpecFlow.TestExecutionReport...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.TextTransform...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.VSTest...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.VSWhere...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.VSWhere.All...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.VSWhere.Latest...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.VSWhere.Legacy...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.VSWhere.Product...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.WiX...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.WiX.Heat...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.XBuild...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Tools.XUnit...
Importing namespace Cake.Common.Xml...
Importing namespace Cake.Core...
Importing namespace Cake.Core.Diagnostics...
Importing namespace Cake.Core.IO...
Importing namespace Cake.Core.Scripting...
Importing namespace Cake.Npm...
Importing namespace Cake.Npm.Install...
Importing namespace Cake.Npm.Pack...
Importing namespace Cake.Npm.Publish...
Importing namespace Cake.Npm.RunScript...
Importing namespace System...
Importing namespace System.Collections.Generic...
Importing namespace System.IO...
Importing namespace System.Linq...
Importing namespace System.Text...
Importing namespace System.Threading.Tasks...
Compiling build script...
Error: Roslyn.Compilers.CompilationErrorException: C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/release-1.0.0/build.cake(37,3): error CS0103: The name 'Npm' does not exist in the current context
   at Roslyn.Scripting.CommonScriptEngine.CompilationError(DiagnosticBag localDiagnostics, DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Roslyn.Scripting.CommonScriptEngine.Compile(String code, String path, DiagnosticBag diagnostics, Session session, Type delegateType, Type returnType, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isInteractive, Boolean isExecute,     CommonCompilation& compilation, Delegate& factory)
   at Roslyn.Scripting.CommonScriptEngine.Execute[T](String code, String path, DiagnosticBag diagnostics, Session session, Boolean isInteractive)
   at Roslyn.Scripting.Session.Execute(String code)
   at Cake.Core.Scripting.ScriptRunner.Run(IScriptHost host, FilePath scriptPath, IDictionary`2 arguments)
   at Cake.Commands.BuildCommand.Execute(CakeOptions options)
   at Cake.CakeApplication.Run(CakeOptions options)
   at Cake.Program.Main()
```

What am I missing on my build server?

Comment: I believe I know what this is! Can you try deleting the `tools/Addins/Cake.Npm` folder on your local machine and run the build again? That should fail with the same error message.

Comment: Well, you are right. Deleting that folder on my local machine has resulted in the same error message as the build server. Now I guess I need to know how to fix it on both machines.

Comment: That was the magic. Apparently the Cake.Npm I had on my development machine was an older version with older syntax. When I moved to my build server, it downloaded a newer version of Cake.Npm so the older syntax did not work. I went to https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Npm and noticed the newer syntax. Updated my Cake script and it is working now. @agc93, if you state your comment as an answer, I will accept your answer since it led me to the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear you worked it out! I had that exact answer queued up for once you confirmed my suspicions, so I've posted it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of a breaking change in the `Cake.Npm` addin. With 0.9.0 the maintainers essentially rewrote the API to use `NpmInstall`, `NpmPack` etc aliases to replace the older `Npm.Install`-style aliases.

You should be able to fix this error by changing the task to something like the below:

```
Task("NpmInstall")
.Does(() =>
{
    NpmInstall(s => s.FromPath("./src/MyProject/"));
});
```

You can see the full documentation for the new API [on the website](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/npm/)

Answer (score 5):

While I agree that the breaking change in the Cake.Npm package was unfortunate, and perhaps could have been handled better, the changes in the API were fully [documented](https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Npm/releases/tag/0.9.0), with suggestions on how to move forward with the necessary changes, and also how to stick to the previous version.  Purely from a semantic versioning point of view, this addin hasn't reached the first public API version number, i.e. 1.0.0, therefore API level changes should be expected, and handled appropriately.

The latter point here is the important one, and the one that I want to further highlight.  In any build system, not just Cake, you want to strive for repeatable, maintainable builds.  You can read for about this [here](https://reproducible-builds.org/).  To that end, it is strongly recommended that to pin to both a [specific version of Cake](http://cakebuild.net/docs/tutorials/pinning-cake-version) and also pin to a specific version of all the addins, tools, and modules that you are using in your build script.  That way, you will always be able to repeat the build, on any system, rather than have a build fail due to a new dependency being published upstream of your application.

What I would recommend in your case would be the following:

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Npm&version=0.8.0
```

That way, going forward, both your local machine, and any build server that you choose to run the build on, will fetch version 0.8.0 of the Cake.Npm package, and will always work.

Then, when you are ready, you can knowingly upgrade the dependency, test to make sure everything is working, and then roll out the change.